# Windows 8 image creation

Tags: windows, windows-8, system-restore, disk-image

http://en.kioskea.net/faq/29239-windows-8-1-how-to-create-a-system-image

If I was to create a system image using this method above, will the external hard drive I save it to be completely wiped and only contain the image or will it still have the rest of the files, no one seems to clarify this.

Thanks

Comment: It will wipe the drive.